# Use of Google API that is for web App

Tags: .net

I'm using Google API for sending group email and manage but that is Console API .

Which is Google API may I use in my .net web-project to send group email or manage all email ID?

Comment: Have you tried using your current code within your web project? It's not clear why you think it wouldn't work.

Comment: yes i have used its showing error that is some namespace are not available in web like  DirectoryService ?